# aftr installing ubuntu windows installation is gone

Tags: 14.04

I've installed the new version of ubuntu on my laptop and I choose to create new partion in my drive. I've allocated 13gb for this. I was able to installed it thinking it will run alongside with my windows, after I restarted my pc for me to check if my windows is still there It automatically load ubuntu, is there any way that I can locate back my windows drive.

Thank,
Badfish

Comment: Possible duplicate of `http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu`

Comment: Please clarify exactly what happens during boot. Do you get the grub screen which then does not show Windows as an option? Have you tried mounting the Windows partition from within Ubuntu? If the partition was actually deleted then follow the link from @vembutech above.

Answer (score 0):

Download and burn to CD/DVD a software called -- Boot-Repair-Disk --  from SOURCEFORGE.net. After burning, insert disk into CD/DVD drive and reboot system into CD/DVD drive, click on -- recommended repair -- and let the software do its MAGIC, and then reboot system. This solves the majority of bootsector/grub/and MBR problems.  I personaly dual boot windows/ubuntu and I also use a lot of other linux flavors and sometimes GRUB gets messed up, and this has always solved my problem. Anyone using linux or dual booting linux with windows should have this simple tool it works GREAT :-)